# Skip 'natural' exit in trap

Tags: bash, exit, trap

My script looks like:

```
trap "$(pwd)/dd-destroy.sh $l-env;$(pwd)/dd-drop.sh $l-db;exit" INT QUIT TERM EXIT

./dd-all.sh $l $l-db $l-env || exit 1

app_ip=$(./dd-status.sh ip $l-env|grep docker-app|awk '{print $3}')
url=http://$app_ip:8080/app/

wget -O /dev/null $url || (echo "access $url failed" && false) || exit 1
```

Now I want this trap launch when error occurs, those 'exit 1' (I can change them there). 
But when nothing happens, like dd-all.sh worked fine, when wget came fine. I do not want to call for destroy.

Can I accomplish this with trap? 
It's not my script, I need to change it a little. Maybe trap is a bad call here?

Comment: `trap` specifies which signals the `dd-destroy.sh...` command should be invoked on. I don't know of any way for that command to test what the error code was when getting an `EXIT` signal. I'd recommend creating a function that has your `dd-destroy.sh ...` stuff in it; have the `trap` line invoke that function but omit the signal `EXIT`; and replace your `exit 1` with `{ that_function; exit 1; }`.

Comment: Why are you listing `EXIT` in the `trap` specification if you don't want the trap to run on exit?

Comment: @tripleee the OP wants the trap to run on normal (non-signalled) exits *but only when the exit code is > 0*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply change the start of your `trap` to check for the return code
of the last command (which will be that of the exit, or the command at
the end of the script) for zero. I.e.

```
trap '[ $? = 0 ] && exit;'"..."
```

where `"..."` is your current string, which should follow with no intervening spaces. An exit within the trap will not trap again.

If your trap is also handling signals, eg SIGINT (control-C), then
the trap is called once for the SIGINT, then once more for the exit. 
You can probably check if trap is being called from SIGINT as the `$?` will be 128+n where n is the signal, so 130 for SIGINT. Remember `$?` will be changed as soon as you give another command, so perhaps start with `rc=$?;` then use `$rc` in your tests.

Comment: Huh, I was skeptical, but I just confirmed you are right. Tested on a v3 `bash` as well as a BusyBox sh (variant of `ash`), works as you say in both cases.

Comment: Great thx, but there's still a little problem that I do not understand.  
    `'trap '[ $? = 0 ] && exit;'"echo 'DUPA'" INT QUIT TERM EXIT  </br>
    sleep 2`
  
when I hit ctrl+c, i see 'dupa' printed twice. Why's that? Is trap handled twice then? When?

Comment: Yes, trap is called once for the sigint, then once for the exit. You can probably check if trap is being called from sigint as the `$?` will be 128+n where n is the signal, so 130 for sigint. Remember `$?` will be changed as soon as you give another command, so perhaps start with `rc=$?;` then use `$rc`.